# Adding an interior 'hero' area with some added php title customization

Tags: php, functions

Ok here it goes. I hope Im at the right place. Sorry if this has been answered I looked over on the regular SO but couldn't find an answer.

I'm currently building  WP site that has a slider area on the homepage. The interior pages will have a smaller 'hero with title for the page/post' for the lack of a better term. Basically Im trying to swap an image and a title for each page inside the small 'hero.'

So I wrote this but I am having trouble getting the title to insert into the div.

```
//Vars
$about = 'about-us-gradient';
$work = 'work-gradient';

if (is_page('about-us')) {
  echo '<div class="hero-interior-inner-gradient'. ' '. $about . '">'. '<div class="hero-overlay">'. add_title() .'</div>'. '</div>';
}                   

elseif (is_page('work')) {
  echo '<div class="hero-interior-inner-gradient'. ' '. $work . '">'. '<div class="hero-overlay">'. add_title() .'</div>'. '</div>';
}

function add_title() {
    if (is_home() ) {
        echo apply_filters('the_title', get_post(get_option('page_for_posts') )->post_title); 
    }  elseif ( is_search() ) { 
        echo 'Search Results';
    } else {
        echo the_title();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to concatenate function result into a string you should be *returning* it, not echoing it. Echo just sends it to output.

Also you are making a typical mistake of confusing two flavor of WP template tags. Convention is the following:

- `the_*` template tags *echo* result immediately;
- `get_the_*` template tags *return* result.

Internally former is usually calling the latter.